# How to hide angular admin views

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, authentication

I want to make an angular app with routes and jwt auth, but I don't want normal users to see the HTML partials of admin views. What's the best way to do this with laravel and angular? People can just put "/partials/adminPage1.html" on the url and see the partial when they are not logged in. My API is secure but I don't want the html to be public.

I want it so this is public:

`index.php`, `publicPartial1.html`, `publicPartial2.html`, etc

and only logged in users can use these files:

`admin.php`, `adminPartial1.html`, `adminPartial2.html`

Comment: First off - kinda just getting out of the way. It shouldn't really matter if if admin views are public. But if you do want to hide them then just use authentication in Laravel to check if the user is an admin on the routes for those views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can/need to approach this in a few ways:

1. when "someone" puts "/partials/adminPage1.html" you need to check in the sever side (by the service you are checking it's permissions/role) then display/redirect to the appropriate route with ReturnUrl in the query for after login redirect.
2. You can be more secured by downloading the routes from the server by requesting them first (per user/role/permission) from a dedicated service, but then you'll need to bootstrap your AngularJS, since routing needs to be loaded with AngularJS life cycle, so in that case you are getting the routes, building them in a provider while bootstrapping AngularJS after getting the routes from the designated service as I mentioned.

*** I would suggest to simply implement option (1) which is straight forward and most commonly used. ***